# How to list all available search templates in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Tried this `localhost:9200/_template?` but it seems to list index templates.

I'd like to list existing **search templates** in the system, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No predefined REST endpoint for that but you can use `GET /.scripts/_search`.

Answer (score 5):

```
GET _cluster/state/?filter_path=metadata.stored_scripts
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

If you index your templates via API then you can try with /_cluster/state. You can find the list of templates under object►metadata►stored_scripts.